# How to draw a figure with output as input with latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, block

I want to draw the exact replica of this figure [image] with latex but I failed to draw the feedback as I want. Thanks for your help. Here is my result and my code.[image]

```
 \documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{schemabloc} 

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\sbStyleLien{ very thick}
\sbStyleBloc{fill=black!30, very thick}


\sbComp[5]{a}%{r1}

\sbBloc[3]{b}{$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{rv}s}$}{a}
      %\sbRelier[$\Delta P_{ref}(s)$]{r1}{a}

                \sbRelier[$\Delta P_{rv}(s)$]{a}{b}

                \sbBloc[3]{c}{$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{T}s}$}{b}
                \sbRelier[$\Delta P_{v}(s)$]{b}{c}
   \sbComph[5]{a1}{c}                  
                \sbRelier[$\Delta P_{m}(s)$]{c}{a1}
                \sbBlocL[3]{d}{$\dfrac{1}{2Hs+D}$}{a1}


    \sbSortie[4]{S1}{d}
    \sbRelier{d}{S1}
    \sbNomLien[0.8]{S1}{$\Delta \omega (s)$}


    \sbDecaleNoeudy[5.5]{d}{v}


    \sbBlocr[10]{r2}{$\dfrac{1}{R}$}{v}


    \sbRelieryx{d-S1}{r2}

    \sbRelierxy{r2}{a}


    \sbDecaleNoeudx[-1]{S1}{t}
    \sbDecaleNoeudy[10]{d}{u}
    \sbDecaleNoeudy[-0.30]{t}{t}

    \sbBlocr[10]{r1}{$\dfrac{K_I}{s}$}{u}

    \sbRelieryx{t}{r1}

    \sbDecaleNoeudx[-5]{a}{r11}
    \sbRelierxy{r1}{r11}
    \sbRelieryx{r11}{a}




 \sbEntree{E1}
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-5]{a1}{E1}

\sbRelier[$\Delta P_{L}(s)$]{E1}{a1}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using Tikz, here's an alternative version.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,positioning}

\tikzset{
    rect/.style={draw, rectangle, minimum width=1.8cm},
    circ/.style={draw, circle, path picture={\draw
(path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west) (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);
}},
    every label/.style={draw=none,font=\scriptsize},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[-{Stealth}, node distance=4em]

\node[rect] (n1) at (0,0) {$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{rv}s}$};
\node[rect, right=of n1] (n2) {$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{T}s}$};
\node[circ, label={[label distance=-4mm]90:$-$},label={[label distance=-4mm]180:$+$}, minimum size=8mm, right = of n2] (c1) {};
\node[rect, right= 1.5cm of c1] (n3) {$\dfrac{1}{2Hs+D}$};
\node[rect, below=1cm of n2] (n4) at (n2.south east) {$\dfrac{1}{R}$};
\node[rect, below=2cm of n1] (n5) at (n1.south east) {$\dfrac{K_I}{s}$};
\node[circ, label={[label distance=-4mm]-90:$-$},label={[label distance=-4mm]180:$+$}, minimum size=8mm, left =of n1] (c2) {};

% Arrows
\draw (n1) -- (n2) node[midway, above] {$\Delta P_{v}(s)$};
\draw (n2) -- (c1) node[midway, above] {$\Delta P_{m}(s)$};
\draw ($(c1)+(0,2)$) -- (c1) node[midway, right] {$\Delta P_{L}(s)$};
\draw (n3) --++ (3cm,0) node[midway, above] (na) {$\Delta \omega (s)$};
\draw (c1) -- (n3);
\draw (na) -- (na|-n4.east) -- (n4);
\draw (n4) -- (n4-|c2.south) -- (c2); 
\draw (na.330) -- (na.330|-n5.east) -- (n5);
\draw (n5) -- (n5-|c2.south) --++ (-2,0) coordinate (a) -- (a|-c2.west) -- (c2);
\draw (c2) -- (n1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, it is almost what I want, but I don't want the first pointer before the comparator, only a 90° angle like in the first drawing (the model), and could the comparator have a cross inside it? like in the one I draw myself.

Comment: @HalimaTambo See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that by default, `\sbRelier` always draw `arrows`, but you can change the line style with `\sbStyleLien`. As this command affects all further lines, it's better to define inside a local scope `{\sbStyleLien{...}\sbRelier...}`

Also looks like `\sbEntree` defines an undrawn node with certain size but you can still use its `.center` as reference. This is what I've done to draw the second feedback line.

`schemabloc` already loads `TikZ` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{schemabloc} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\sbStyleLien{very thick}
\sbStyleBloc{fill=black!30, very thick}

\sbEntree{r1}
\sbComp[3]{a}{r1}

\sbBloc[5]{b}{$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{rv}s}$}{a}

\sbRelier[{$\Delta P_{rv}(s)$}]{a}{b}

\sbBloc[4]{c}{$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{T}s}$}{b}
\sbRelier[$\Delta P_{v}(s)$]{b}{c}

\sbComph[7]{a1}{c}                  
\sbRelier[$\Delta P_{m}(s)$]{c}{a1}

\sbBlocL[3]{d}{$\dfrac{1}{2Hs+D}$}{a1}

\sbSortie[4]{S1}{d}
\sbRelier{d}{S1}
\sbNomLien[0.8]{S1}{$\Delta \omega (s)$}

\sbDecaleNoeudy[5.5]{d}{v}
\sbBlocr[10]{r2}{$\dfrac{1}{R}$}{v}
\sbRelieryx{d-S1}{r2}
\sbRelierxy{r2}{a}
\sbDecaleNoeudx[-1]{S1}{t}

\sbDecaleNoeudy[10]{d}{u}
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-0.30]{t}{t}
\sbBlocr[10]{r11}{$\dfrac{K_I}{s}$}{u}
\sbRelieryx{t}{r11}

\sbEntree{E1}
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-5]{a1}{E1}
%
\sbRelier[$\Delta P_{L}(s)$]{E1}{a1}

{
\sbStyleLien{-, line cap=rect}
\sbRelierxy{r11}{r1.center}
}
\sbRelier{r1.center}{a}
%

\end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

[image]

*Update*

You can understand what happens with `\sbRelier[$\Delta P_{c}(s)$]{r1.center}{a}` if you look at page 11 from [`Schemabloc`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/schemabloc/schemabloc.pdf) documentation. It's written in french, but `TikZ` is `TikZ`:

[image]

`\sbReiler` has three parameters, an optional text (`#1`) and line origin and destinations coordinates. This text is written over/below the line due to `auto` option and the reference point is the mid point betweein `r1.center` and `a`.

You have two solutions to avoid overlapping of text with comparator:

Increase distance between origin and comparator:

```
\sbEntree{r1}
\sbComp[3]{a}{r1} %<---- Change 3 with 4, 5, ...
```

or place the comment with a `node` command (and `positioning` library):

```
\sbRelier{r1.center}{a}
\node[above left= .333pt of a.west]{$\Delta P_{c}(s)$};
```

Comment: Hello yes it is what I tried to do. Thank you. A last thing, when I put a text at the input of the comparator it overflows. Like in the picture below. How to remediate to this?

Comment: @HalimaTambo: Answer updated.