# Multi level latex figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, block

I am trying to do the following figure [image] with shemabloc, but I didn't succed mainly due to the first two comparators that I cannot place correctly. Thank you for your help. Here is my code.

```
  \documentclass[ french,tikz,border=5]{standalone}

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{palatino}
 \usepackage{mathpazo}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
 \usepackage{pgf}
 \usepackage{schemabloc}
 \begin{document}



 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \centering
 \sbStyleLien{ very thick}
 \sbStyleBloc{fill=black!30, very thick}

 \sbEntree{I}
 \sbCompSum[5]{a}{I}{+}{-}{}{}
 \sbDecaleNoeudy[-5]{a}{I}
 \sbBloc[4]{k}{$\dfrac{K_{I1}}}{s}$}{a}
 \sbComp[5]{a1}{k}
 \sbBloc[3]{b}{$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{rv1}s}$}{a1}
                \sbRelier{I}{a}
                \sbRelier[$ACE_{1}(s)$]{a}{k}
                                    \sbRelier{k}{a1}
                \sbRelier[$\Delta P_{rv1}(s)$]{a1}{b}

                \sbBloc[3]{c}{$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{T1}s}$}{b}
                \sbRelier[$\Delta P_{v1}(s)$]{b}{c}
 \sbComp[5]{a2}{c}     

                \sbRelier[$\Delta P_{m1}(s)$]{c}{a2}
                \sbBlocL[3]{d}{$\dfrac{1}{2H_{1}s+D_{1}}$}{a2}


 \sbSortie[4]{S1}{d}
 \sbRelier{d}{S1}
 \sbNomLien[0.8]{S1}{$\Delta \omega_{1} (s)$}


 \sbDecaleNoeudy[5.5]{d}{v}


 \sbBlocr[10]{r2}{$\dfrac{1}{R_{1}}$}{v}


 \sbRelieryx{d-S1}{r2}

 \sbRelierxy{r2}{a1}

 \sbDecaleNoeudy[10]{d}{u}

 \sbBlocr[10]{r1}{$B_{1}$}{u}
 \sbRelieryx{d-S1}{r1}
 \sbRelieryx{u}{r1}

 \sbRelierxy{r1}{a}

 \sbEntree{E1}
 \sbDecaleNoeudy[-5]{a2}{E1}

   \sbRelier[$\Delta P_{L1}(s)$]{E1}{a2}

   %------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \sbCompsum[5]{a3}{-}{-}{}{}
  \sbBloc[3]{k2}{$\dfrac{K_{I2}}{s}$}{a3}
  \sbComph[5]{a4}{k2}
  \sbBloc[3]{b1}{$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{rv2}s}$}{a4}

                \sbRelier[$ACE_{2}(s)$]{a3}{k2}
                                    \sbRelier{k2}{a4}
                \sbRelier[$\Delta P_{rv2}(s)$]{a4}{b1}

 \sbBloc[3]{c1}{$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{T2}s}$}{b1}
                \sbRelier[$\Delta P_{v2}(s)$]{b1}{c1}
 \sbComp[5]{a5}{c1}   

                \sbRelier[$\Delta P_{m2}(s)$]{c1}{a5}
                \sbBlocL[3]{d1}{$\dfrac{1}{2H_{2}s+D_{2}}$}{a5}


  \sbSortie[4]{S2}{d1}
  \sbRelier{d1}{S2}
  \sbNomLien[0.8]{S2}{$\Delta \omega_{2} (s)$}


  \sbDecaleNoeudy[-5.5]{d1}{v1}


  \sbBlocr[10]{r3}{$\dfrac{1}{R_{2}}$}{v1}


  \sbRelieryx{d1-S2}{r3}

  \sbRelierxy{r3}{a4}

  \sbDecaleNoeudy[-10]{d1}{u1}

  \sbBlocr[10]{r4}{$B_{2}$}{u1}
  \sbRelieryx{d1-S2}{r4}
  \sbRelieryx{u1}{r4}

  \sbRelierxy{r4}{a3}

  \sbEntree{E2}
  \sbDecaleNoeudy[5]{a5}{E2}

   \sbRelier[$\Delta P_{L2}(s)$]{E2}{a5}


   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end {document}
```

Comment: What is `mlp`? Please kick out everything which is not needed for this question.

Comment: mlp means multi language package. It is used with frencle an additional dictionnary developped for french users.

Comment: *Do you need it for this question?* If not, it can be removed from the MWE. *If the problem cannot be reproduced without it, please provide a link to the package.* The package is not part of TeX Live, for example, and is not on CTAN. But providing a link should only be done if the package is required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok, I am removing it.

Comment: Isn't this the complete picture of [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253968/4778)?

Comment: Yes it is the complete figure of that one.

Comment: When you use code written by somebody else, it is courteous to provide a link and to attribute the code to the author who wrote it. In some cases, this is a legal requirement (i.e. your right to use the code at all depends on your attributing it correctly). However, the fact that common courtesy requires it is a stronger reason, in my opinion.

Comment: The code has been written by me and not by somebody else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[french,tikz,border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{schemabloc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\sbStyleLien{ very thick}
\sbStyleBloc{fill=black!30, very thick}

\sbEntree{I}
%\node[draw] at (I) {I1};
\sbCompSum[5]{a}{I}{+}{-}{}{}
%\node[draw] at (a) {};
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-5]{a}{I}
%\node[draw] at (I) {I2};
\sbRelier{I}{a}
\sbBloc[4]{k}{$\dfrac{K_{I1}}{s}$}{a}
\sbRelier[$ACE_{1}(s)$]{a}{k}

\sbComp[5]{a1}{k}
\sbRelier{k}{a1}

\sbBloc[3]{b}{$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{rv1}s}$}{a1}
\sbRelier[$\Delta P_{rv1}(s)$]{a1}{b}

\sbBloc[3]{c}{$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{T1}s}$}{b}
\sbRelier[$\Delta P_{v1}(s)$]{b}{c}

\sbComp[5]{a2}{c}
\sbRelier[$\Delta P_{m1}(s)$]{c}{a2}

\sbBlocL[3]{d}{$\dfrac{1}{2H_{1}s+D_{1}}$}{a2}

\sbSortie[4]{S1}{d}
\sbRelier{d}{S1}

\sbNomLien[0.8]{S1}{$\Delta \omega_{1} (s)$}

\sbDecaleNoeudy[5.5]{d}{v}
\sbBlocr[10]{r2}{$\dfrac{1}{R_{1}}$}{v}
\sbRelieryx{d-S1}{r2}
\sbRelierxy{r2}{a1}

\sbDecaleNoeudy[10]{d}{u}
\sbBlocr[10]{r1}{$B_{1}$}{u}
\sbRelieryx{d-S1}{r1}
%\sbRelieryx{u}{r1}
\sbRelierxy{r1}{a}

\sbEntree{E1}
\sbDecaleNoeudy[5]{a2}{E1}
\sbRelier[$\Delta P_{L1}(s)$]{E1}{a2}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-5]{I}{I2}
\sbCompSum[0]{a3}{I2}{-}{-}{}{}
\sbBloc[4]{k2}{$\dfrac{K_{I2}}{s}$}{a3}
\sbComph[5]{a4}{k2}
\sbBloc[3]{b1}{$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{rv2}s}$}{a4}
\sbRelier[$ACE_{2}(s)$]{a3}{k2}
\sbRelier{k2}{a4}
\sbRelier[$\Delta P_{rv2}(s)$]{a4}{b1}
\sbBloc[3]{c1}{$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{T2}s}$}{b1}
\sbRelier[$\Delta P_{v2}(s)$]{b1}{c1}
\sbComp[5]{a5}{c1}   
\sbRelier[$\Delta P_{m2}(s)$]{c1}{a5}
\sbBlocL[3]{d1}{$\dfrac{1}{2H_{2}s+D_{2}}$}{a5}
\sbSortie[4]{S2}{d1}
\sbRelier{d1}{S2}
\sbNomLien[0.8]{S2}{$\Delta \omega_{2} (s)$}
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-5.5]{d1}{v1}
\sbBlocr[10]{r3}{$\dfrac{1}{R_{2}}$}{v1}
\sbRelieryx{d1-S2}{r3}
\sbRelierxy{r3}{a4}
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-10]{d1}{u1}
\sbBlocr[10]{r4}{$B_{2}$}{u1}
\sbRelieryx{d1-S2}{r4}
\sbRelieryx{u1}{r4}
\sbRelierxy{r4}{a3}
\sbEntree{E2}
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-5]{a5}{E2}
\sbRelier[$\Delta P_{L2}(s)$]{E2}{a5}
%------------------------------------------------------
\sbDecaleNoeudy[-5]{d-S1}{S3}
%\path (d-S1) -- (d1-S2) coordinate[midway] (aux);
\sbCompSum[0]{S3}{S3}{+}{-}{}{}
\sbRelierxy{d}{S3}
\sbRelierxy{d1}{S3}
\sbBlocL[-7]{d0}{$\dfrac{P_s}{s}$}{S3}
\sbRelierxy{d0}{a}
\sbRelierxy{d0}{a5}
\sbRelierxy{d0}{a3}
\sbRelierxy{d0}{a2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes it is that. Finally, you show that it is possible by schemabloc . Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but I failed to have a figure like yours when I compiled the code.

Comment: @HalimaTambo With this information I cannot help. The code I posted works for me. I've tested again copying from here.

Comment: I test the code by copying it in a new latex document and it definitively works. Sorry the problem was due  to my latex editor. Thanks.