# Achieve a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I want to do a figure like this one [image]

But I can't achieve it. I am a beginners in tikz.

Thanks for your Help. I add the code and the result I get.[image]

```
\documentclass[french, tikz,border=5]{standalone}



\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{13}{8}{8} 

 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
 \usepackage{pgf}


   \usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,calc}
    \tikzset{
   block/.style={
    shape=rectangle,
    fill=black!30,
    draw=black,
    minimum width=1.15cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
    label=above:\strut#1
    },
    circ/.style={draw, circle, path picture={\draw
   (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding               box.north west) (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding  box.north east);
         }},
         sum/.style args={+ #1 - #2}{
           shape=circle,
          fill=white,
          draw=black,
        minimum size=0.75cm,
         label={#1:$+$},
        label={#2:$-$}
            },
           sum/.default={+ 195 - 255},
             flow/.style={
           draw=black, very thick,
            -Triangle
           },
            Delta (s)/.style args={"#1_#2" #3}{
            insert path={
             node [midway, #3=0.25cm] {$\Delta #1_{\scriptsize#2}(s)$}
          }
         }
        }
      \begin{document}
         \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.30cm]

   \node [block=Régulateur de vitesse, right=of s2] (governor) {$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{rv}s}$};
    \node [block=Turbine, right=of governor] (turbine) {$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{T}s}$};

     \node[circ, label={[label distance=-4mm]90:$-$},label={[label distance=-4mm]180:$+$}, minimum size=8mm, right = of turbine] (s3) {};
      \node[circ, label={[label distance=-4mm]-90:$-$},label={[label  distance=-4mm]180:$-$}, minimum size=8mm, left =of governor] (s2) {};

       \coordinate [above=of s3] (input);
       \node [block=Générateur et charge, right=of s3] (power system)  {$\dfrac{1}{2Hs+D}$};

      \node [block=  , below=1.5cm of turbine] (speed drop) {$\dfrac{1}{R}$};
  \node [block, below=1.5cm of speed drop] (KI) {$\dfrac{K_I}{s}$};
  \node [block, above=0.2cm of KI] (pro) {$K_P$};
  \node[circ, label={[label distance=-4mm]-90:$+$},label={[label   distance=-4mm]90:$+$}, minimum size=8mm, left = of KI] (s4) {};
  \coordinate [right=2cm of power system] (end);


  \draw [flow] (s2)       -- (governor)    node[midway, below] {$\Delta P_{rv}(s)$};        
  \draw [flow] (governor) -- (turbine)  node[midway, below] {$\Delta P_{v}(s)$};
  \draw [flow] (turbine)  -- (s3)       node[midway, below] {$\Delta P_{m}(s)$};
  \draw [flow] (input)    -- (s3)       [Delta (s)={"P_L" right, near start}];
   \draw [flow] (s3) -- (power system);
  \draw [flow] (power system) -- (end)  [Delta (s)={"\omega_" above, near end}];
   \draw [flow] ($(power system.east)!1/4!(end)$) |- (speed drop)
    node [midway, above left] {Boucle primaire};
   \draw [flow] (speed drop) -| (s2);
    \draw [flow] ($(power system.east)!1/2!(end)$) |- (KI)
    node [midway, above left] {Boucle secondaire};
    \draw [flow] (KI) -- (s4)  
  %\draw [flow](s4) -- (s4-|s2.south) --++ (-1,0) coordinate (a) -- (a|-    s2.west) -- (s2)  [Delta (s)={"P_{ref}" above=2cm of s2,left=0.25cm of s2}];

   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Se my answer to question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258325/tikz-diagram-additional-right-angle-and-space/258330#258330, it may help you in effort to draw your picture.

Comment: This example with `\usepackage{schemabloc}` can help: [Example: Schemabloc](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/schemabloc/)

Comment: Have you taken the code from this site? I remember answering a question with this exact scheme, but I can't find it.

Comment: Ah yes, here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253972/4778 ... I see you changed something. Not too hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can position the node along the path, so you save lines in your code. If you don't want the arrow tip, add `-` to the path properties, like:

```
\draw[flow,-] ...
```

Here's the complete version.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,arrows.meta,calc} 
\DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{13}{8}{8} 

\tikzset{
    block/.style={
        shape=rectangle,
        fill=black!30,
        draw=black,
        minimum width=1.15cm,
        minimum height=1cm,
        label=above:\strut#1
    },
    circ/.style={draw, circle, path picture={\draw
        (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding               box.north west) (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding  box.north east);
    }},
    sum/.style args={+ #1 - #2}{
        shape=circle,
        fill=white,
        draw=black,
        minimum size=0.75cm,
        label={#1:$+$},
        label={#2:$-$}
    },
    sum/.default={+ 195 - 255},
        flow/.style={
        draw=black, very thick,
        -Triangle
    },
    Delta (s)/.style args={"#1_#2" #3}{
        insert path={
        node [midway, #3=0.25cm] {$\Delta #1_{#2}(s)$}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.30cm]

\node [block=Régulateur de vitesse] (governor) {$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{rv}s}$};
\node [block=Turbine, right=of governor] (turbine) {$\dfrac{1}{1+\tau_{T}s}$};

\node[circ, label={[label distance=-4mm]90:$-$},label={[label distance=-4mm]180:$+$}, minimum size=8mm, right = of turbine] (s3) {};
\node[circ, label={[label distance=-4mm]-90:$-$},label={[label  distance=-4mm]180:$-$}, minimum size=8mm, left =of governor] (s2) {};

\coordinate [above=of s3] (input);
\node [block=Générateur et charge, right=of s3] (power system)  {$\dfrac{1}{2Hs+D}$};

\node [block=  , below=1.5cm of turbine] (speed drop) {$\dfrac{1}{R}$};
\node [block, below=1.5cm of speed drop] (KI) {$\dfrac{K_I}{s}$};
%\node [block, above=0.2cm of KI] (pro) {$K_P$};
\node[circ, label={[label distance=-4mm]-90:$+$},label={[label   distance=-4mm]90:$+$}, minimum size=8mm, left = of KI] (s4) {};
\coordinate [right=2cm of power system] (end);


\draw [flow] (s2)       -- (governor)    node[midway, below] {$\Delta P_{rv}(s)$};        
\draw [flow] (governor) -- (turbine)  node[midway, below] {$\Delta P_{v}(s)$};
\draw [flow] (turbine)  -- (s3)       node[midway, below] {$\Delta P_{m}(s)$};
\draw [flow] (input)    -- (s3)       [Delta (s)={"P_L" right, near start}];
\draw [flow] (s3) -- (power system);
\draw [flow] (power system) -- (end)  [Delta (s)={"\omega_" above, near end}];
\draw [flow] ($(power system.east)!1/4!(end)$) |- (speed drop)
    node [midway, above left] {Boucle primaire};
\draw [flow] (speed drop) -| (s2);
\draw [flow] ($(power system.east)!1/2!(end)$) |- (KI)
    node [midway, above left] {Boucle secondaire};
\draw [flow,-] (KI) -- (s4);

\draw[flow,-] ($(KI.east)+(1.7cm,0)$) -- ++ (0,1.3) coordinate (temp)  -- (temp-|s4) node[thin,block, midway] {$K_P$} -- (s4);
\draw[flow] (s4) -- ++ (-4,0) coordinate (tempp) -- (tempp|-s2) -- (s2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```